# Eclipse not opening out of the box

Tags: java, eclipse

i just downloaded eclipse IDE and it's not running out of the box. what do i do? the error log is

```
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.ant.core [57]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.variables; bundle-version="[3.1.0,4.0.0)"
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.core.variables; bundle-version="3.2.800.v20130819-1716"; singleton:="true"
       org.eclipse.core.variables [83]
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.runtime; bundle-version="[3.3.0,4.0.0)"
           -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.core.runtime; bundle-version="3.11.0.v20150405-1723"; singleton:="true"
              org.eclipse.core.runtime [80]
                Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.jobs; bundle-version="[3.2.0,4.0.0)"; visibility:="reexport"
                  -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.core.jobs; bundle-version="3.7.0.v20150330-2103"; singleton:="true"
                     org.eclipse.core.jobs [75]
                       Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.7))"
```

`at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:434)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1582)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1561)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1533)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1476)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)`

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ant.launching 4 0 2017-12-26 11:31:52.440

Comment: What version of Java do you have installed?

Answer (score 0):

You are using a version of Java that is too old. You should be using at least Java 8.

Answer (score 0):

Hi from the logs i can see you are using JDK 1.7 which is not supported by Eclipse Neon or Oxygen.

Either Use **Eclipse Mars** which supports 1.7 or update to 1.8.